# create timestamp from dataframe columns and use as xaxis in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got some a dataframe with the `date`, `hour`, and `minute` in columns. I would like to plot the `value` column by some sort of timestamp. Anyway to do this?

```
> head(fl)
        date hour min value
1 2014-02-23     0    0    81
2 2014-02-23     0    1    65
3 2014-02-23     0    2    73
4 2014-02-23     0    3    81
5 2014-02-23     0    4    89
6 2014-02-23     0    5    69
...
```

Right now I'm using ggplot2, but it combines the minutes of every hour and day together :(

```
ggplot( fl, aes( min,  value) ) + geom_line()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function `ISOdatetime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec)`:

```
fl <- data.frame(date=c('2014-02-23', '2014-02-22'), hour = c(0,0), min = c(1,2))

zip <- function(x) do.call(Map, append(list(c), x))
args <- unname(append(zip(strsplit(as.character(fl$date), '-')), list(fl$hour, fl$min, 0)))
fl$timestamp <- do.call(ISOdatetime, args)

print(fl)
#         date hour min           timestamp
# 1 2014-02-23    0   1 2014-02-23 00:01:00
# 2 2014-02-12    0   2 2014-02-12 00:02:00
```

Answer (score 3):

An `as.POSIXct` alternative giving the same result as @RobertKrzyzanowski

```
fl <- data.frame(date=c('2014-02-23', '2014-02-22'), hour = c(0,0), min = c(1,2))
fl$stamp <- with(fl, as.POSIXct( paste(date,hour,min), format="%Y-%m-%d %H %M")) 

#> fl
#        date hour min               stamp
#1 2014-02-23    0   1 2014-02-23 00:01:00
#2 2014-02-22    0   2 2014-02-22 00:02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
fl$datetime <- ymd_hm(paste(fl$date,fl$hour,fl$min,sep='-'))
ggplot(fl, aes( datetime, value) ) + geom_line()
```

Comment: thanks. I'm getting an error though.
    > fl$datetime <- ymd_hm(paste(fl$date,fl$hour,fl$min,collapse='-'))
    Warning message:
    All formats failed to parse. No formats found

Answer (score 0):

```
df<- within(df[5:6], { DT=format(as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time, sep = ' ')),
                                 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
                     })
```